# Limit this javascript regex match to 26 character results

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using this regex to match hastags #LIKE #this

It works great.

```
/(?!\b)(#\w+\b)/g
```

But i would like to limit it to hashtags with 26 characters.

Can i modify this to get this result?

Comment: `/(?!\b)(#\w{1,26}\b)/g`

Comment: you were first Mr Green, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `But i would like to limit it to hashtags with 26 characters.`

```
/(?!\b)(#\w{1,26}\b)/g
```

should work.

Basically you replace `\w+` (1 or more word characters) with `\w{1,26}` (between 1 to 26 word characters)

Comment: +1, you don't need the 1 in `{1,26}` though, could be simplified to `{,26}`

Comment: @RobM.: When I tried: `/^\w{,5}$/.test('12345')` it returned false but `/^\w{1,5}$/.test('12345')` returned true.

Comment: Crap, you are right, I knew that one of the params was optional, was thinking of {1,}. My mistake, time for bed :P